# How to create my own component to render icons in element-plus?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

In element-plus we already have icons for example `<i-mdi-edit />`

how can use these icons so i can create my own component

`<Icon name="edit" />`

and i pass the name property so i can get the icon

my `Icon` component as follows;

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

let props = withDefaults(defineProps<{ name: string }>(), {
      name: "edit",
});

let component = ref(`i-mdi-${props.name}`);
</script>

<template>
   <component :is="component" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components=) for that.
For example, in your case, and assuming you have the `name` prop registered, you can use something like:

```
<component :is="`i-mdi-${name}`"></component>
```

Edit: Since you mentioned element plus, here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-river-j9c7ss?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FIcon.vue). However, in this case, it seems a bit redundant to do like you want.

Comment: ok maybe because i'm using vite i should import the icon component , thank you)